# How to select the max value of the last 6 digits of the entries in the column in SQL

Tags: sql, infor-eam

I am trying to select the maximum value of the last 6 digits in a list of strings

This is for creating an Inbox Query in Infor EAM

OBJ_CODE is the column and R5OBJECTS is the table. I have tried the following code but the number returned is 0.

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT(OBJ_CODE,6)) FROM R5OBJECTS
```

My list looks like this

```
AAAA100000
AAAA100001
AAAA100002
AAAA100003
AAAA100004
AAAA100005
...
AAAA100999
...
BBBB100006
BBBB100007
BBBB100008
BBBB100009
BBBB100010
```

So the expected output would be 100999

Comment: What data you get if you remove `MAX`?

Comment: The value returned is 0. I think this is because in Infor EAM inbox, the system only allows a single value (not lists) to be displayed.

Comment: This code works for me!!!

Comment: SELECT MAX(OBJ_CODE)FROM R5OBJECTS WHERE OBJ_CODE LIKE 'AAAA%'

Comment: this returns "The SQL Statement for an Inbox Code can only return one column and the value in that column must be a number."

Answer (score 0):

It seems this table R5OBJECTS is too big, and your sql query performance didn't pass the base configuration parameter.

If using Inbox -> Set your INBXSCOR to **50** and try your query again.

If using KPI -> Set your KPISCOR to **50**

**SQL Statement**

> Enter the SQL statement to calculate the number of applicable records
>   for the inbox entry. The system automatically populates SQL Statement
>   Text. Note:  SQL Statement cannot exceed the performance score limit
>   defined in the INBXSCOR installation parameter.

https://docs.infor.com/eam/11.3.2/en-us/eamolh/cdh1498150395934.html

Comment: My apologies i've been trying to return the value in the KPI's section and not inbox which i have been mistakenly using.

However, when i do try to set it up as an inbox query it returns the error message "The SQL Statement for an Inbox Code can only return one column and the value in that column must be a number."

Comment: I see, so you need to check KPISCOR value in installation parameter

Comment: When i change the KPISCOR parameter to 999999, the returned value is still 0

Comment: When changing the KPISCOR parameter to 50, the returned value is still 0.

Comment: The value should be 119569

Comment: according to the error when trying to set up this query as an inbox, the sql statement  us bit returning one column or the value in that column is not a number

Answer (score 0):

Although this code works perfectly form me in SQL Server 2016, I add additional function to convert `string` to `int` to be sure:
`SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(OBJ_CODE,6))) FROM R5OBJECTS`

Comment: In Infor EAM when i try this use this code i get the error message "The system failed to carry out this function because of the environment or configuration problems."

Comment: I changed `CAST` (in sql) into `val` (in Infor EAM)[http://www.baanboard.com/node/4361]

Comment: I get the error "The SQL Statement is invalid: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 'VAL' is not a recognized built-in function name." when changing `CAST` to     `VAL`

Comment: I've updated my code and used the `convert` function. But maybe there are some configuration problems in your environment. Because `Convert` and `Cast` is an internal function.

Comment: Still returns  "The system failed to carry out this function because of the environment or configuration problems." 

This could be a system limitation